remove tabularray first row sep lines
Whats proper way to remove first row col sep lines of tabularray table? For below example the vertical lines around A,B should be removed.
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  vspan=minimal, hspan=minimal,
  hline{2,3,4}={blue},
  colspec={|c|c|},
  cell{2}{1}={r=2}{c},
  colsep=2pt,
  rowsep=2pt,
  row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
}
  A & B \\
  C & D \\
    & E \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

Output:


You can move the vlines definition from the colspec to the vlines property and use indexing to only activate certaing segments of it. In your case, from the second (2) to the last (Z).
I also changed your format commands from cmd to font.
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            vspan=minimal, hspan=minimal,
            hline{2,3,4}={blue},
            colspec={cc},
            vlines = {2-Z}{black},
            cell{2}{1}={r=2}{c},
            colsep=2pt,
            rowsep=2pt,
            row{1}={font=\bfseries},
        }
        A & B \\
        C & D \\
        & E \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


